# Port Scanner Shows All Ports Closed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and am confused as to why the script I've written below
isn't working right, I'm at the stage now where I can't see the wood for the
trees.

I've tried to create the port scanner from the 'Violent Python' book. I believe
the book uses Python 2.6 but I'm creating it using Python 3.7.

Using hints and tips in other posts on this website I've got the port scanner to
do scans of some of the computers on my lab setup, however, the scans always 
show ports to be 'closed'. I used nmap to scan the computers to make sure I had
some open ports to use in my port scanner script.

My script is below.

```
import optparse
from socket import *
from threading import *
screenLock = Semaphore(value=1)

def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
    try:
        connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        connSkt.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
        connSkt.send('ViolentPython\r\n')
        results = connSkt.recv(100)
        screenLock.acquire()
        print('[+]%d/tcp open'% tgtPort)
        print('[+]' + str(results))
    except:
        screenLock.acquire()
        print('[-]%d/tcp closed'% tgtPort)
    finally:
        screenLock.release()
        connSkt.close()

def portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
    try:
        tgtIP = gethostbyname(tgtHost)
    except:
        print("[-] Cannot resolve '%s': Unknown host"%tgtHost)
        return
    try:
        tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtIP)
        print('\n[+] scan results for: ' + tgtName[0])
    except:
        print('\n[+] Scan results for: ' + tgtIP)
    setdefaulttimeout(1)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort)))
        t.start()

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog '+ '-H <target host> -p <target port>')

    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', help='specify target port[s] seperated by comma')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = [p.strip() for p in options.tgtPort.split(',')]

    if (tgtHost == None) | (tgtPorts[0] is None):
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)

    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run the script from Powershell with:

> python 01_portscan_revA.py -H 192.168.0.207 -p 22,80,135,443,445

Which produces the following output:

```
[+] Scan results for: 192.168.0.207
[-]22/tcp closed
[-]135/tcp closed
[-]445/tcp closed
[-]139/tcp closed
[-]80/tcp closed
[-]443/tcp closed
```

I'm sure it's not a million miles away, I'd be very greatful for any help
anyone can offer to try and solve this problem.

Many Thanks

Thank you all for getting back to me. I've had another look at my script and
done some changes to it, I'm not sure if these are correct.

I changed def connScan as follows to capture errors.

```
def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
try:
    connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connSkt.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
    connSkt.send (b'ViolentPython\r\n')
    results = connSkt.recv(100)
    screenLock.acquire()
    print('[+]%d/tcp open'% tgtPort)
    print('[+]' + str(results))
except Exception as e:
    screenLock.acquire()
    print('Error: {0}'.format(str(e)))
    print('[-]%d/tcp closed'% tgtPort)
finally:
    screenLock.release()
    connSkt.close()
```

Initially I was getting a 'expecting bytes type object' error so i put a 'b' in
front of the 'Violentpython' to convert to bytes.

Now the output looks like this:

```
[+] scan results for: Cheryls
[+]139/tcp open
[+]b'\x83\x00\x00\x01\x8f'
Error: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the 
remote host
[-]445/tcp closed
Error: timed out
[-]80/tcp closed
Error: timed out
[-]443/tcp closed
Error: timed out
[-]135/tcp closed
Error: timed out
[-]1030/tcp closed
```

I get timed out errors as suggested by Vovanrock2002.

Comment: Have you tried printing the error in the `except` block?

Comment: Also, just because a port is open it doesn't mean that it will accept any data you send to it. Many servers will kick you off and forcefully close the conection the minute you send unexpected data (like `ViolentPython\r\n` in your case) which will cause an exception, which you'll wrongly detect as a closed port.

Comment: Never use a bare `except` statement in your code. This will hide basic mistakes like syntax errors, misspelled variables, or attempts to access attributes that don't exist.  Always catch a specific list of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, applications on listed ports close the connection as soon as they realize `'ViolentPython\r\n'` is not a part of a protocol they support. On the other hand, `results = connSkt.recv(100)` accompanied by `setdefaulttimeout(1)` will make recv throw `socket.timeout` exception.

According to python docs `connSkt.connect` can throw timeout as well. So you basically need:

1. To stop catching things via bare `except`. If you don't know what exception to wait for, temporarily catch just `Exception`, examine caught objects and then replace it with more specific things.
2. To split `connect` and `send + recv` into different `try` blocks.

Comment: Hi Vovanrock2002, 
Thanks for looking at my post. You were correct with the time out errors,
I added and exception to the script to capture them. Is splitting the connect and send + receive the only way of getting around the time out, as I'm not how to do this yet.